# How do I call other event methods?

Tags: c#, methods, event-handling, save, menustrip

```
private void save(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (File.Exists(fileLabel.Text))
    {
        // this will save in the debug folder unfortunately
        FileStream outputFileStream = new FileStream(fileLabel.Text, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputFileStream);

        // writing block (too long code)


        writer.Close();
        outputFileStream.Close();
    }

    else
    {
        saveAs(); // no overload
    }
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is if a user presses `Save` they will save the file without the dialog. This code checks if the file exists to save. If it doesn't exist it will redirect to the `saveAsDialog` method.

```
private void saveAs(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // code is similar (it works fine if user clicks the menu strip)
}
```

However, when I call the `saveAs()` method it will not overload. Now I've never called event handlers in my `Form1` class so I wouldn't know how to use it. All the handlers are from double-clicking the form design.

So what parameters do I have to put on the `saveAs()` method call if I want it to do the same thing as if the user selected it from the menu strip?

Comment: Why not use a helper method and call that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this to trigger your event:

```
saveAs(this, EventArgs.Empty)
```

Answer (score 4):

Pass on the save parameters:

```
saveAs(sender, e);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a method in one place suggests refactoring code into a common method that can be used anywhere.

Comment: Uhm how do you do that? I'm not really sure on this.

Comment: Instead of calling the ui method directly create a utility dll and create a save method and save with one parameter (save as) call these from ui methods

Answer (score 2):

write a `Method` using the `code` of your `save` event

```
void saveOrSaveAs()
{
  if (File.Exists(fileLabel.Text))
  {
    // this will save in the debug folder unfortunately
    FileStream outputFileStream = new FileStream(fileLabel.Text, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputFileStream);

    // writing block (too long code)

    writer.Close();
    outputFileStream.Close();
  }
  else
  {
    saveAs(); //If You have already written code for saveAs() method.
  }
}
```

And `Call` this method in both `events` as

```
private void save(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  saveOrSaveAs();
}
```

Again `call` this `method` in your `saveAs` `Event`.

```
private void saveAs(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  saveOrSaveAs();
}
```